# How refresh a single control in xib?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, uiview

I have a xib with a 2 UIViews named subview1 and subview2. In subview1 a UILabel is palced and in subview2 a UITableView is placed.

I want to refresh the subview1 to change the label text at a particular time but no need to refresh tableview that time. After few operations again I need to refresh the tableview but no need to refresh the label.

How can I achieve this ?.

Thanks.

Comment: post some of your code.. how you are doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try next way.

Load xib by **loadNibNamed** and just replace wanted subview.

```
NSArray * views = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"your xib name" owner:self options:nil];
```